# How do I access the UITableView in the XCode "Navigation Based Application"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

This "wizard" gives me a tableview to work with when I build and run.  RootViewController is subclassing UITableViewController. Opening up the XIB, there is a table view, but what is the name of the tableview instance being displayed?

I'm trying to reload the tableview after a receiving data from an asynchronous URL request and I don't know what object to call "reload" on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UITableViewController class has a property `tableView` to access the UITableView it's using.

So you can do that inside the RootViewController class:

```
[self.tableView reload];
```